# Ext.getCmp('panel') gives this.el is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs3

I have a border layout in which I have to expand and collapse the east region for some views, 
The screen works fine at the start, but when you click on the refresh button of the browser and if the east region is collapsed, then you got the east region as collapsed which according to my understanding should not happen because the extJS code is executed from the start every time you hit a refresh, and therefore the east region must be visible after doing a refresh.

To make the east region expanded every time a user hits a refresh 
I tried to to the following

```
    Ext.getCmp('center_panel').add({
        id: 'center_panel_container',
        layout: 'border',
        defaults: {
        'border': true
        },    
        items:[{
           id : 'header_panel',
           layout: 'fit',
           region: 'north',
           height: 30,
           items: [tbar]
        },{
           id: 'master_panel',
           layout: 'fit',
           region: 'center',
           width: '60%',
           bodyStyle:{"background-color":"white"},
           autoScroll: true,
           items: [panelLeft,panelLeftSchd,panelLeftStartUp]
        }, {
           id: 'report_panel',
           layout: 'fit',
           region: 'east',
           width : '40%',
           split:true,
           autoScroll: true,
           items: [panelRight,  panelRightStartUp]
    }]   
 });
        Ext.getCmp('report_panel').expand(true);
```

But I am getting the following error **this.el is null or not an object** .

How to make the east region expanded whenever a user hits a refresh each time

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `Ext.getCmp('report_panel')` is not rendered at the time you're trying to call its expand method. That is because Ext-JS sometimes uses a `setTimeout` when laying out components. The simplest solution is to wait for the render event and call expand from that handler

```
{
       id: 'report_panel',
       layout: 'fit',
       region: 'east',
       width : '40%',
       split:true,
       autoScroll: true,
       items: [panelRight,  panelRightStartUp],
       listeners: {
           render: function(panel) {
              panel.expand()
           }
       }
}
```

You can also wait for the `afterlayout` event of the parent container.

Comment: thanks for answering, but your solution did not work, after searching for some 2 hours, I found out that the splitter has  stateful:true, by default, so when a user do a refresh , the splitter remember the previous session state, to correct it I added one line stateful:false,

Comment: @AnuragSharma Just to be accurate, it's incorrect that say that my solution didn't work. It's more accurate to say that though the solution does solve the problem with the error message you were getting (which *is* your question), it did not solve the problem you were trying to get at. I'm sure you understand the difference since you still marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: @JuanMendesI am extremely sorry if my post hurts your feeling, but I would like to make sure this wasn't my intention at all

Comment: @AnuragSharma Your post didn't hurt my feelings. It just didn't contain accurate information.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind, before posting anything in the future :).

Answer (score 0):

The splitter tends to remember its state, so upon refresh the splitter sets itself to the position where it was in his previous session so to make it forgot his state do the followiing

```
{
       id: 'report_panel',
       layout: 'fit',
       region: 'east',
       width : '40%',
       split:true,
       **stateful : false,**
       autoScroll: true,
       items: [panelRight,  panelRightStartUp]
}
```